# Barra de busqueda en Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

Estoy tratando de implementar una barra de busqueda para filtrar por valores de mi información, el codigo flitra pero tras unos segundos despues de la busqueda vuelve a mostrar todos los elementos, o sea elimina el filtro.

Supongo que cuando ejecuta FilterCoops vuelve a ejecutar inicializeCoops por eso el array vuelve a su estado inicial

¿Como puedo hacer para que el array conserve su estado en el filtro de busqueda?

Mi archivo home.ts es este:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CoopProvider } from '../../providers/coop/coop';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {
  cooperatives: any = [];
  categories: any = [];


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
              public coopProv: CoopProvider,
              public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController,
              ) {}

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.inicializeCoops()
    this.inicializeCategoies();
  }

  inicializeCoops() : void {
    this.coopProv.getCoops()
    .subscribe(
      (data) => { // Success
          this.cooperatives = data;

      },
      (error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      }
    )
  }


  inicializeCategoies() {
    this.coopProv.getCategories()
    .subscribe(
      (data) => { // Success
        this.categories = data;
      },
      (error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      }
    )
  }



  filterTechnologies(param : any) : void
  {
     this.inicializeCoops();


     let val : string   = param;

     // DON'T filter the technologies IF the supplied input is an empty string
     if (val.trim() !== '')
     {
        this.cooperatives = this.cooperatives.filter((item) =>
        {
          return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1 || item.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        })
     }
  }

}
```

Y el provider es este:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

/*
  Generated class for the CoopProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class CoopProvider {
  urlApi = 'http://miurl.algo:8000/'

  cooperatives: any;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient){
  }

  getCoops() {
    return this.http.get(this.urlApi + 'api/v1/cooperatives/')  
    }


  getCategories() {
      return this.http.get(this.urlApi + 'api/v1/categories/')
    }

}
```

Dejo un gif con la grabación de la pantalla para que puedan ver el comportamiento de la app

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías utilizar un pipe, te comparto este [ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-pipe-generic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tu función **this.coopProv.getCoops()** se ejecuta de forma asíncrona por ser un observable, la solución en tu caso, es realizar el filtro sin llamar más datos.

```
filterTechnologies(param: any): void {
     let val: string = param;
     // DON'T filter the technologies IF the supplied input is an empty string
     if (val.trim() !== '') {
        this.cooperatives = this.cooperatives.filter((item) => {
          return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1
            || item.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        });
     }
  }
```

Otra posible solución es agregar una promesa para esperar a que estén listos los resultados y después filtrarlos.

```
  inicializeCoops(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((result) => {
      this.coopProv.getCoops().subscribe((data) => { // Success
          this.cooperatives = data;
          result();
        }, (error) => {
          console.error(error);
          result();
        }
      );
    });
  }

  async filterTechnologies(param: any): void {
     await this.inicializeCoops();
     let val: string = param;
     // DON'T filter the technologies IF the supplied input is an empty string
     if (val.trim() !== '') {
        this.cooperatives = this.cooperatives.filter((item) => {
          return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1
            || item.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        });
     }
  }
```

Si no dominas el uso de promesas y observables te recomiendo investigar sobre programación reactiva.

Comment: Gracias Juan, me sirvió la primera segerencia que me diste. Solo tuve que agregar otra variable cooperatives_filter